# Complicated SQL Query, listing a tree in single query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Oracle SQL (10g) table with data related to bill of material. One item for example has a list of raw material and that list may contain an item with its own bill of material and in that list there may be an item which may have its own bill of material.

I need to list bill of material, with its related items and if there any sub items, then that list of items and if those items have any list, then that list, etc.etc.....
We don't know the tree level of items, it is random.

I'm now unable to post image, I will explain as follows:

Item A ------ Raw Material 1
Item A ------ Raw Material 2
Item A ------ Semi Finished Item 1 - Raw Material 3
Item A ------ Semi Finished Item 1 - Raw Material 4
Item A ------ Semi Finished Item 1 - Semi Finished Item 2 - Raw Material 5
Item A ------ Semi Finished Item 1 - Semi Finished Item 2 - Semi Finished Item 3 - Raw Material 6
etc,etc....

New Example:

ITEMCODE BOMCODE QTY 
ABCD       XYZ  1
ABCD2      XYZ  8
ABCD3      XYZ  3
ABCD4   XYZ 56
ABCD76  ABCD3   1
ABCD98  ABCD3   5
ABCD34  ABCD4   2
ABCD21  ABCD4   8
ABCD90  ABCD98  9
ABCD31  ABCD98  2

there are 3 fields in the table, itemcode, bomcode, qty.

This example is for 'xyz' item, to produce 'xyz' item we need the items listed in the itemcode with the qty mentioned and if you look there are some items like 'abcd3', 'abcd4', which have their own bill of material, same for 'abcd98'. I am not aware of the levels as it is random, it can have any number of levels.

Comment: Your requirement is unclear. Can you maybe show us what query you have tried? Also, if you can't post an image, upload it on an image hosting service and provide the link if possible.

Comment: Develop a [hierarchical query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) for this task.

Comment: This cannot be answered IMO. If you don't know the tree level how would we? and how can we propose a query without table names and field names? We will also require some sample data to trial any proposed query.

Comment: I can not directly answer your question but you really should use Google. Search for example usages for the function `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`.

Comment: @CodeNewbie -  have added an example in the question above. THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by @Used_By_Already, the following query is the answer to my question:

```
SELECT
  LEVEL, BOMCODE, ITEMCODE, QTY
FROM
  BOMS
WHERE
  LEVEL <= 30
  START WITH BOMCODE      = 'XYZ'
  CONNECT BY PRIOR ITEMCODE = BOMCODE
ORDER BY
  LEVEL, BOMCODE, ITEMCODE, QTY
;
```

Comment: You should just comment his post, and above all accept his answer then !

Comment: This should NOT be ticked as the answer, oh well, I understand what you have done. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This result:

```
| LEVEL | BOMCODE | ITEMCODE | QTY |
|-------|---------|----------|-----|
|     1 |     XYZ |     ABCD |   1 |
|     1 |     XYZ |    ABCD2 |   8 |
|     1 |     XYZ |    ABCD3 |   3 |
|     1 |     XYZ |    ABCD4 |  56 |
|     2 |   ABCD3 |   ABCD76 |   1 |
|     2 |   ABCD3 |   ABCD98 |   5 |
|     2 |   ABCD4 |   ABCD21 |   8 |
|     2 |   ABCD4 |   ABCD34 |   2 |
|     3 |  ABCD98 |   ABCD31 |   2 |
|     3 |  ABCD98 |   ABCD90 |   9 |
```

Produced by this query:

```
SELECT
  LEVEL, BOMCODE, ITEMCODE, QTY
FROM
  BOMS
WHERE
  LEVEL <= 30
  START WITH BOMCODE      = 'XYZ'
  CONNECT BY PRIOR ITEMCODE = BOMCODE
ORDER BY
  LEVEL, BOMCODE, ITEMCODE, QTY
;
```

I used a table name of `BOMS`, and the number of levels used in the where clause is arbitrary, it's there as a "safety" on the number of recursions really.

see [This SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/88485/3)

Not sure if this is what you wanted. Maybe the following:

```
PATH
------------------------------
XYZ/ABCD
XYZ/ABCD2
XYZ/ABCD3
XYZ/ABCD4
XYZ/ABCD3/ABCD76
XYZ/ABCD3/ABCD98
XYZ/ABCD4/ABCD21
XYZ/ABCD4/ABCD34
XYZ/ABCD3/ABCD98/ABCD31
XYZ/ABCD3/ABCD98/ABCD90
```

by:

```
SELECT
   LPAD(' ', 2*level-1)||'XYZ'||SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ITEMCODE, '/') "Path"
FROM
  BOMS
WHERE
  LEVEL <= 30
  START WITH BOMCODE      = 'XYZ'
  CONNECT BY PRIOR ITEMCODE = BOMCODE
ORDER BY
  LEVEL, BOMCODE, ITEMCODE, QTY
;
```

Comment: have added an example in the question above. THanks

Comment: thank you very very much, I got the result what i wanted with your first query. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, will you be `accepting the answer` then? This indicates the question is complete by the way and is an important part of the question/answer process.